# Placing triangles on a line, minimizing the greatest distance

Tags: algorithm, line, packing

I need to place triangles (different shapes) on a straight line with the distance between the first triangle placed and the last triangle placed as low as possible. The triangles are allowed to touch the line with only one corner, but they need to be placed on top of the line, they are not allowed to go through the line.

I can rotate the triangles, but I cannot alter their size or shape.

I tried placing the triangles sort of circle-like around one point of the line  until 180° are reached and repeated the process, but I doesn't seem like this is a very efficient algorithm.

[image: Example (non-altered)]

Comment: This question could do with a couple of illustrations.

Comment: Are you allowed to rotate the triangles -- choosing the side that will touch the base line?

Comment: I keep attacking this and finding more cases that negate my earlier attacks.  I've found cases where we want the triangles touching at the top; where the simple radial arrangement isn't at all optimal; ...

Comment: Are the triangles required to have a full side along the line, or is it OK if they touch the line at just one vertex?

Comment: The triangles are allowed to touch the line with only one edge, they just need to touch it somehow

Answer (score 0):

First, rotate triangles, so shortest size is horizontal (make shortest side a base). After this you'll have least total length.

Second, Sort triangles by angle of lower right corner and collect them in that order. After this, they will not intersect.

Proof of second step

```
   B          D
   |\        /|
   | \      / |
   |  \    /  |
   |   \  /   |
   |____\/____|
   A    C     E
```

For sorted triangles ACB < CED.
CED + CDE + DCE = 180 -> DCE < 180 - CED
ACB < CED and DCE < 180 - CED -> ACE + DCE < 180, thus triangles will not overlap.

Comment: This is pretty good if I need to place a full side along the line, but I only have to place one tiny bit of the triangle along the line. But if I had another Triangle with the lengths BC, CD, DB, then your solution would place it with BD on the bottom instead of on the top, which would use more space.

Comment: Uh, it was not clear to me if they can touch the line with the corner.